# Run command2 only if command1 succeeded in cmd windows shell

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

How do we combine commands in cmd shell language such that the second command is only executed if the first command successfully completed?

something like following bash-command

```
make && ./a.out
```

`a.out` is only executed if `make` was successful

Comment: Why is this tagged with both [cmd] and [bash]?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The following

```
command1 && command2
```

should work on `cmd` as well. Quote from [here](http://htipe.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/multiple-commands-on-a-single-windows-command-line/):

> *When using cmd.exe, you can put multiple commands on the same line by using ‘&’ or ‘&&’ between commands.  Using a single ampersand (&) will cause the first command and then the second command to be run in sequence.  Using double ampersands (&&) introduces error checking.  **The second command will run only if the first command is successful**.*

Comment: Is there any way to break run multiple commands on **different** lines? A whole long script with error checking all the way through it looks terrible on a single line.

Comment: as ABCD.ca said below. add "\" at the end of the line. This escapes the newline character. "command \" then on another line, 
"&& conditional_command"

Answer (score 23):

An AND list has the form

```
command1 && command2
```

command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.

An OR list has the form

```
command1 || command2
```

command2 is executed if and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status.  The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last command executed in the list.

Comment: if your command1 is long then you can escape the end of the line that contains command1 with a trailing backslash: `verylongcommand1 \ `. Then on line 2 you can have ` && command2 `

Comment: @ABCD.ca Maybe you can escape your newline characters?